# When is normal force at its greatest inside a loop

Tags: classical-mechanics

Imagine a particle going around inside a loop with radius R. At what point is the normal force largest? Constant speed.

If the loop was the unit circle with $R=1$, would there be any normal force at $x=1$ and $x=-1$?

[image]

Comment: Is there gravity? How are gravitation and the circle aligned?

Comment: @Jasper yes there is gravity

Comment: It's a loop on earth

Comment: How is the circle aligned? What is x?

Comment: @Jasper x was just an example of a value on the x axis on a regular unit circle. I will draw it and update

Comment: @Jasper the arrow on the drawing is just the direction

Comment: Also, how does the ball move?

Comment: @JerrySchirmer slides. It's a particle, not ball

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming gravity points to the negative y direction, the normal force of the ring acting on the particle is minimal at y=1 and largest at y=-1.

To keep the particle on the circle, a constant inwards force is necessary. Without gravity, this means that this force always is the normal force, making it equal at all points.

Now we also have gravity that "supports normal force" at the top, so less normal force is required there, and at the bottom, the normal force must act against gravity and provide the centripetal force, so it is largest at the bottom.

Comment: Is the increase in normal force from y=1 to y=-1 linear?

Comment: Probably not, I guess that there will be some trigonometry involved. Also linear in which coordinate?  X? Time?

Comment: in terms of x yes

Comment: A typical flaw when solving this problem is having a poor motivation for the choice of the top point to get the required equation when looking for the minimum initial potential energy to complete it. For students, it may be not so clear that the trajectory is symmetric (as it isn't if the top is not reached), and that if the ball keeps contact before the top, it will also do after.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a normal force at x=1 and x=-1.  You can calculate the size of the normal force by using Newton's 2nd Law where the acceleration is centripetal.

Answer (score 0):

Normal force is maximum at y=-1 and minimum at y=1
You can calculate normal force at these 2 points using Newton's 2nd law
At y=-1.    R-mg=mv^2/r    =>R=mg+mv^2/r
At y=1.     R+mg=mv^2/r   =>R=mv^2/r-mg
Where R is the normal reaction
Now for x=1,-1 Note that a force is required to cause centripetal acceleration of the particle for it to move on this circle hence a normal reaction has to be there in order to provide this centripetal acceleration.